# use radio button to move image

Tags: java, swing

I've created a gui with two jbuttons and added an icon to one of those buttons. Now I would like to add some functionality by adding two radio buttons and make the icon move from one jbutton to the other (from left to right, and from right to left). I know I need an action listener on the radio buttons, I imagine it's an `if else` statement. But I can't figure out how to point my if statement to the jbutton currently holding the icon.

```
    public Testing() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 600, 600);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        setContentPane(contentPane);

        JPanel panel_1 = new JPanel();
        panel_1.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(0, 0, 12, 0));
        contentPane.add(panel_1, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        JLabel lblSomeGui = new JLabel("SOME GUI");
        panel_1.add(lblSomeGui);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(12, 12, 12, 12));
        contentPane.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 0, 12, 0));

        JButton btnRight = new JButton("");
        btnRight.setIcon(new ImageIcon(Testing.class.getResource("/btn/resources/balloon80.jpg")));
        btnRight.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        panel.add(btnRight);

        JButton btnLeft = new JButton("");
        btnLeft.setBackground(Color.BLACK);


        panel.add(btnLeft);

        JPanel panel_2 = new JPanel();
        panel_2.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(12, 0, 0, 0));
        contentPane.add(panel_2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        JRadioButton radioButtonLeft = new JRadioButton("Left");
        radioButtonLeft.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if(btnRight.setIcon() == ("/btn/resources/balloon80.jpg") ){

                }

            }
        });
        buttonGroup.add(radioButtonLeft);
        panel_2.add(radioButtonLeft);

        JRadioButton radioButtonRight = new JRadioButton("Right");
        radioButtonRight.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            }
        });
        buttonGroup.add(radioButtonRight);
        panel_2.add(radioButtonRight);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for ‍‍`if else` statement.

```
final ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(Testing.class.getResource("/btn/resources/balloon80.jpg"));
radioButtonRight.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      btnRight.setIcon(icon);
      btnLeft.setIcon(null);
   }
});

radioButtonLeft.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        btnRight.setIcon(null);
        btnLeft.setIcon(icon);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would probably just define the Icon as an instance variable in your class:

```
private Icon balloon = new ImageIcon(Testing.class.getResource("/btn/resources/balloon80.jpg"));
```

Then when you create the button you can use:

```
JButton btnRight = new JButton("");
btnRight.setIcon( balloon );
```

or even easier:

```
JButton btnRight = new JButton( balloon );
```

Finally in the ActionListener for the "left" radio button you can use:

```
btnLeft.setIcon( balloon );
btnRight.setIcon( null );
```

Comment: so i would not need to start by setting up the icon on the jbutton

Comment: never mind , ignore that previous statement it was a bit dumb from my part.

Comment: @user3803668, my original comment said to set the icon when you create the button. See the updated code.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following code to your action listener:

```
if(btnRight.getIcon() == null){
 // set icon to btnLeft
} else {
 // set icon to btnRight
}
```

Hope this helps.